How to make a scrollable tab view?
Since a tab view cannot be put inside a scroll view I am trying to use the new iOS 17 methods to make a custom tab using scroll views. In my code below, if you comment out the first VStack that is labeled "doesn't work" and uncomment the second VStack view that works, you will see that my custom tab view functions well.
However, I want to make a profile view that has a header, middle content that scrolls up (does not pin), a bar that pins at the top, and then a tab view. Doing this causes my custom tab view to fail.
I was not able to find any website that had a custom tabview that functions inside a scroll view, so I think this is important to address.
import SwiftUI

#Preview(body: {
    SwiftUIView()
})

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: TabProfile?
    @State private var tabProgress: CGFloat = 0
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    
    var body: some View {
        
        //----- THIS DOESNT WORK
        
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Color.red.frame(height: 100)
                .overlay {
                    Text("Header").foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .offset(y: 20).bold()
                }
            
            ScrollView {
                LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                    
                    Color.blue.frame(height: 100)
                        .overlay {
                            Text("Some content").foregroundStyle(.white).bold()
                        }
                    
                    Section(header: buttonTab()) {
                        rcontent()
                    }
                }
            }
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
        
        
        
        //-----THIS WORKS---------
        
//        VStack {
//            buttonTab()
//            
//            rcontent()
//        }
    }
    func rcontent() -> some View {
        GeometryReader {
            let size = $0.size
            
            ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                LazyHStack(spacing: 0) {
                    SampleView(.purple)
                        .id(TabProfile.hustles)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    
                    SampleView(.red)
                        .id(TabProfile.jobs)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    
                    SampleView(.blue)
                        .id(TabProfile.likes)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    
                    SampleView(.green)
                        .id(TabProfile.sale)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                    
                    SampleView(.orange)
                        .id(TabProfile.question)
                        .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                }
                .scrollTargetLayout()
                .offsetX { value in
                    let progress = -value / (size.width * CGFloat(TabProfile.allCases.count - 1))
                    tabProgress = max(min(progress, 1), 0)
                }
            }
            .scrollPosition(id: $selectedTab)
            .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
            .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
            .scrollClipDisabled()
        }
    }
    func buttonTab() -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(TabProfile.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { tab in
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text(tab.rawValue)
                        .font(.callout)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .contentShape(.capsule)
                .onTapGesture {
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                        selectedTab = tab
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .tabMask(tabProgress, tabCount: TabProfile.allCases.count)
        .padding(.horizontal, 8)
        .background {
            GeometryReader {
                let size = $0.size
                let capusleWidth = size.width / CGFloat(TabProfile.allCases.count)
                ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                        .fill(.gray)
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .offset(y: 40)
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(width: capusleWidth, height: 2)
                        .offset(x: tabProgress * (size.width - capusleWidth), y: 40)
                }
            }
        }
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func SampleView(_ color: Color) -> some View {
        ScrollView(.vertical) {
            LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 2), content: {
                ForEach(1...10, id: \.self) { _ in
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                        .fill(color.gradient)
                        .frame(height: 150)
                }
            })
            .padding(15)
        }
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .scrollClipDisabled()
        .mask {
            Rectangle()
                .padding(.bottom, -100)
        }
    }
}

enum TabProfile: String, CaseIterable {
    case hustles = "Hustles"
    case jobs = "Jobs"
    case likes = "Likes"
    case sale = "4Sale"
    case question = "???"
}


Do I understand correctly, that you want to have a view that behaves like section's header which can be attached to the top once you scroll until specific point and also replicate page tab view?
Also, I had to remove a few lines of code, since the complier was not happy about them, since declaration had not provided in your code.

Additionally, I think, it would be helpful, if you attach a few images or even a video with an example of desired result. So it would be easier for people to help you.

@Suprafen yes that is what Im after. I will add images to this question shortly. What portion of the code was undeclared? I copy and pasted this code into a new project and it worker.

Answering your previous question, for instance: .offsetX and .tabMask.

Here is my solution:
import SwiftUI

#Preview(body: {
    SwiftUIView()
})

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    @State private var selectedTab: TabProfile?
    @State private var tabProgress: CGFloat = 0
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme
    let counts: [TabProfile.RawValue : Int] =  ["Hustles" : 20, "Jobs" : 2, "Likes" : 20]
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(alignment: .leading){
            Color.red.frame(height: 100)
                .overlay {
                    Text("Header").foregroundStyle(.white)
                        .offset(y: 20).bold()
                }
            GeometryReader {
                let size = $0.size
                
                ScrollViewReader(content: { proxy in
                    ScrollView {
                        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 0, pinnedViews: [.sectionHeaders]) {
                            
                            Color.blue.frame(height: 100)
                                .overlay {
                                    Text("Some content").foregroundStyle(.white).bold()
                                }
                                
                            
                            Section(header: buttonTab().id("top")) {
                                ScrollView(.horizontal) {
                                    LazyHStack(alignment: .top, spacing: 0) {
                                        SampleView(.purple, count: counts["Hustles"] ?? 20)
                                            .id(TabProfile.hustles)
                                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                                        
                                        SampleView(.red, count: counts["Jobs"] ?? 2)
                                            .id(TabProfile.jobs)
                                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                                        
                                        SampleView(.blue, count: counts["Likes"] ?? 20)
                                            .id(TabProfile.likes)
                                            .containerRelativeFrame(.horizontal)
                                    }
                                    .scrollTargetLayout()
                                    .offsetX { value in
                                        let progress = -value / (size.width * CGFloat(TabProfile.allCases.count - 1))
                                        tabProgress = max(min(progress, 1), 0)
                                    }
                                }
                                .scrollPosition(id: $selectedTab)
                                .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                                .scrollTargetBehavior(.viewAligned)
                                .scrollClipDisabled()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
                    .onChange(of: selectedTab) { oldValue, newValue in
                        let old = counts[oldValue?.rawValue ?? ""] ?? 0
                        let new = counts[newValue?.rawValue ?? ""] ?? 0
                        
                        if old > new {
                            withAnimation { proxy.scrollTo("top", anchor: .bottom) }
                        }
                    }
                })
            }
        }
        .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
    func buttonTab() -> some View {
        HStack(spacing: 0) {
            ForEach(TabProfile.allCases, id: \.rawValue) { tab in
                HStack(spacing: 10) {
                    Text(tab.rawValue)
                        .font(.callout)
                }
                .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
                .padding(.vertical, 10)
                .contentShape(.capsule)
                .onTapGesture {
                    UIImpactFeedbackGenerator(style: .light).impactOccurred()
                    withAnimation(.snappy) {
                        selectedTab = tab
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        .tabMask(tabProgress, tabCount: TabProfile.allCases.count)
        .padding(.horizontal, 8)
        .background {
            GeometryReader {
                let size = $0.size
                let capusleWidth = size.width / CGFloat(TabProfile.allCases.count)
                ZStack(alignment: .leading){
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 0)
                        .fill(.gray)
                        .frame(height: 1)
                        .offset(y: 40)
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 5)
                        .fill(.blue)
                        .frame(width: capusleWidth, height: 2)
                        .offset(x: tabProgress * (size.width - capusleWidth), y: 40)
                }
            }
        }
        .background(colorScheme == .dark ? .black : .white)
    }
    @ViewBuilder
    func SampleView(_ color: Color, count: Int) -> some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: Array(repeating: GridItem(), count: 2), content: {
            ForEach(1...count, id: \.self) { _ in
                RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 15)
                    .fill(color.gradient)
                    .frame(height: 150)
            }
        })
        .padding(15)
        .scrollIndicators(.hidden)
        .scrollClipDisabled()
        .mask {
            Rectangle()
                .padding(.bottom, -100)
        }
    }
}

enum TabProfile: String, CaseIterable {
    case hustles = "Hustles"
    case jobs = "Jobs"
    case likes = "Likes"
    case sale = "4Sale"
    case question = "???"
}


Is this meant to be a solution to your question or is this more information about the question? If this is a solution, please include a description of what was wrong and how this code fixes the issue. Code-only answers are not nearly as useful. If this is acutally more information for the question, please delete this "answer" and put the information in the question.

Solution. It's essentially a view that functions as a scrollable tabview.

It will help future readers enormously if you can explain why it was the solution (in the answer itself, prior to the code).
